# Insert a range of dates and should be unique with another column

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, date-arithmetic, connect-by

I have table

```
CREATE TABLE T_TEST 
( KURS_NUMBER NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
 KURS_ID NUMBER NOT NULL, 
DATEKURS DATE NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT UNIQUE2 UNIQUE
 (KURS_ID,DATEKURS)
 );
```

TRIGGER for kurs_number

```
create or replace trigger TR_INSERT_TEST01
  before insert on test01  
  FOR EACH ROW

declare
  -- local variables here
begin
  IF :NEW.KURS_NUMBER IS NULL
    THEN SELECT SEQ_TEST.NEXTVAL INTO :NEW.KURS_NUMBER FROM DUAL;
    END IF;
end TR_INSERT_T_TEST;
```

How can I insert data to kurs_id which will contain only one digit '1'
and datekurs will contain date in order period from 2017year 1 january to 31 december 2017year ( or random date )

```
connect by level 365
```

---

This code works very well but if I want to use my trigger for new column kurs_number it doesn't work  due (not enough values). I guess that should be in different way.

```
insert into t_test 
select 1 
       , date '2017-01-01' + (level-1)
from dual
connect by level <= 365
/
```

Comment: `kurs_id` is a primary key, so how can it be " only one digit '1'" for 365 values of `datekurs`?

Comment: You'r right i modifed a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This trick generates 365 rows. We can do arithmetic with dates so adding `(level-1)` to a root date generates 365 dates.

```
insert into t_test 
select SEQ_TEST.NEXTVAL
       , 1 
       , date '2017-01-01' + (level-1)
from dual
connect by level <= 365
/
```

> "not enough values"

You changed the structure of the target table so you needed to change the projection of the query to match. The revised version includes the additional primary key column.

---

> "i want to use my trigger for new column kurs_number"

You can make this a procedure with parameters for `kurs_id` and the target year.
As a bonus this code handles leap years correctly.

```
create or replace procedure generate_kurs_year_recs
    ( p_kurs_id in number
      , p_kurs_year in varchar2 )
is
    last_dayno number;
begin
    /* find number of days in year */
    select to_number(to_char(to_date( p_kurs_year||'-12-31', 'yyyy-mm-dd')
                    , 'DDD'))
    into last_dayno
    from dual;

    /* generate records for year */
    insert into t_test 
        select SEQ_TEST.NEXTVAL
               , p_kurs_id 
               , to_date( p_kurs_year||'-01-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd') + (level-1)
        from dual
        connect by level <= last_dayno;
end generate_kurs_year_recs;
/
```

Call the procedure like this:

```
begin
    generate_kurs_year_recs(1,'2017');
end;
```

To call from a trigger you will need to pass parameters somehow, presumably using values from the trigger's table.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: APC can you help me to represent same code but in PL/SQL ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. How do you want this done in PL/SQL?

Comment: APC its works now ) your procedure but i cant executed. For p_kurs_year ( string) what should i type ?

Comment: The year you want to generate. So 2017 for the current year.

Comment: Tells me that some data inserted but not at all in deal.Nothing in query select * from t_test;.  I'm just putting to p_kurs_id = 1 to p_kurs_year = 2017;

Comment: I've tested it and the code works as expected. So clearly you're doing something wrong but I can't see what it is. Have you issued a COMMIT in the session where the procedure runs?

Answer (score 0):

This will insert all dates in order

```
insert into t_test (kurs_id, datekurs)
with CTE (DD) as
(
select to_date('20170101','YYYYMMDD') as DD
from dual
union
select DD +1
from CTE
where DD < to_date('20171231','YYYYMMDD')
)
select  row_number() over(order by DD) as kurs_id, DD as datekurs
from CTE
```

Comment: Thank you very much